# How to correctly design a django database?

Tags: django, django-models, orm

I have been learning Django recently, before, I used to design the ER models and all that stuff by myself, although I'm not an expert on databases. I have some questions that I couldn't find anywhere.

In terms of designing the database, does a Django developer use only the UML diagrams related to the models or does he/she designs the ER models and then the tables?

If the developer only uses the UML diagrams, is database normalization necessary or even applicable in this case?

In my ignorance I opted to design the models as UML because I like to have diagrams and it seemed appropriate to me. Is this the right approach?

[UML diagram of django models](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L41s6.png)

Thank you.

Comment: I think using UML diagrams it does normalisation itself as you break up the tables. When I develop models I don't create any diagram just create the models and i know that is bad practice so i am interested to know the answer of this question also this question is future proof that is why upvoted.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.